# PHP MVC dialog validation flow - how to go from view´s form to controller without loosing the context

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I´m builind a PHP MVC based application. I´ve worked with MVC in the past and know the concepts, although PHP is something new for me.

I´m following[this tutorial here](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/) to structure my project, with some changes to reflect my necessities...

I´m facing a problem regarding the way I come from a `form` submit back to my original controller, preserving the context. (My low PHP skill may explain that misunderstanding...)

Let´s go to code:

Here is my **index.php** (the entry point for every call from client):

```
if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action']))
{
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}
else 
{
    $controller = 'Root';
    $action = 'home';
}

require_once('/view/layout.php');
```

The **layout.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">


<?php require_once("library/view/header.php"); ?> // Load header

<body>
        <?php 
            require_once("library/controller/routes.php"); // Route controller/action

            require_once("library/view/footer.php"); // Load footer
        ?>
</body>
```

The **routes.php:** ( to route the path to the correct controller and action)

```
    function call($controller, $action)
    {
        $filename = 'controller/class.' . $controller . 'Controller.php';

        if (!file_exists($filename))
        {
            $errorMsg = "ERROR: File not found: " . $filename . " for Controller:" . $controller . " and Action:" . $action;
            throw new Exception($errorMsg);
        }

        require_once ($filename);

        switch ($controller)
        {
            case 'Root':
                $controllerObj = new RootController();
                break;
        }

        $controllerObj->{ $action }();
    }

    call ($controller, $action);
```

The **class.RootController.php:** - The controller for the Root.

```
public function home () 
{
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        require_once('library/view/root/login.php');
    else
        require_once('library/view/root/home.php');
}

public function authenticate ($username, $password) 
{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

    // Authenticate logic
    if ($auth == true)
    {
        ==> Go to a different controller/view.
    }
    else
    {
       $errorMsg = "Problems authenticating.";
       return $errorMsg;
     }
}

public function error($controller, $action, $errorMessage)
{
    echo "Error in " . $controller  . ' Action" . $action;
    echo $errorMessge;
}
```

And finally the login view (**login.php**):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <label>Username:</label> 
    <br> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>"> <br> <br> <label>Password:</label>

    <br> 
    <input type="password" name="password"> 

    <br> <br> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

    <br> <br> 

    <span style="color: red"><?php echo $errorMsg;?>&nbsp</span>
</form>
```

My problem is:

The way it is, when I click the submit button, it redirects to index page, but without the `$controller` and `$action` context. So there there is no way to route to the `authenticate` function on the `RootController()`;

So, here are my questions:

1. How can I check the entered data, return an error message in case of error or change the Controller and Action in case of success?
2. Do I need to go through the `index.php` on every data validation?
3. Is it possible to go directly from the `form` to the `authenticate` function in the already loadaded `RootController()`, returning the error message in case of failure?
4. Is there a better way to do this form validation?

I´m pretty sure I´m missing something very basic here, but I don´t know what is...

Help and comments very appreciated.

Comment: `header('Location: ... );` perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's great your making your own MVC, its a great way to learn to code. I plan to roll my own one day.

To answer these points

> 1) How can I check the entered data, return an error message in case of error or change the Controller and Action in case of success?

This is done using a header, this is the same header as you set the content type with, such as for ajax, html, or what have you, ie the response header.  The important thing here is that you cannot call header location after doing output, any output even a blank space.

```
 header('Location: www.yoursite.com/success?m=you failed!');
 ext;
```

The exit here is essential, because you are redirecting but the script for the page will continue to run, often with unfortunate consequences.

> 2) Do I need to go through the index.php on every data validation?

Isn't that the point of the MVC framework? It's called the front controller or entry point.

> 3) Is it possible to go directly from the form to the authenticate function in the already loaded RootController(), returning the error message in case of failure?

Using AJAX you could come close but it's doubtful because there is user input that needs to take place, so there is no way around making another request.  Sorry, it's just the way it works.

> 4) Is there a better way to do this form validation?

See number 2. You could do a login popup but that should be in addition of a standard login form.

Typically the way it works is you would have a controller for log in

```
 www.yoursite.com/index.php/login  ( you can hide the index.php with mod rewrite )
```

Then in your `$_SERVER` super global you will find the request uri or something similar that will contain, the uri (uri is imagined instead of a real page).  This goes through index.php to a router to the controller for login. Which displays the page.  Then you have another method in your controller submit login.. etc.  That gets ran when the form is submitted, then using header after processing you direct them to another imaginary resource.  The thing to do with a login is to have a check in the path somewhere and store the page they want, when you send them to the login page.

For example I want to go to this page

```
 www.yoursite.com/index.php/members
```

But i am not logged in so I go here

```
www.yoursite.com/index.php/login?r={www.yoursite.com/index.php/} // urlencode between the { }
```

Then on success, instead of giving them a canned message just give them the page they want, or some kind of dashboard.  If they fail take them back / or better yet just leave them on the login page with an appropriate message.

I should note that typically a router and uri will be setup this way,

```
 {domain}/index.php/{controller class}/{controller method}/ ...additional input.
```

So for extensibility you would want something like this,

```
 www.yoursite.com/index.php/members/login
```

And with some basic mod rewrite you could get it to this

```
www.yoursite.com/members/login
```

It's important to use the uri part of the request because it's like an extra way to keep the context, without using the $_POST or $_GET methods.

Comment: The header would go in the view or in the controoler ? In my case how would the header look like ?

Comment: In my opinion nothing but html goes in a view ( with a template language of course ). but no business logic only display logic.  So redirection would be part of the controller, it controls the flow of the request.  Any call on a server is a request, then the server serves the response.  It's really simple, keep them on the login page, or send them to where they want to go.  Take a look at `var_export( $_SERVER)` there is a bunch of stuff you need in there.

Comment: Very nice explanation.. I got the idea, now learing how to implement - doint it myself... Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see here is that you are calling the `layout.php` right from the front controller (`index.php`), when you don't know yet what kind of output you'll need. For instance, should you redirect the user? Respond to an AJAX request with a JSON? You can't do any of these if you already sent HTML.

If you can, take a look at [PHP mini](http://www.dev-metal.com/mini-extremely-simple-barebone-php-application/). It's a very simple framework for working with MVC in PHP, yet it gives a solid foundation you can work on and even improve. It even has some similarities with your current implementation, but there are quite a few things that already have been done that you don't have to write from scratch.